# Listbox in mvc with data from excel

Tags: model-view-controller, listbox

I want to create a listbox with data from excel but I don't know how. It should look like in this example https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxDataEditorsDemos/Editors/ListBox.

When I copy this code I have an error message in Models:

```
public static ListEditSelectionMode SelectionMode { get; set; }
```

**namespace name could not be found.**

What should I do? Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

You didnt add in the namespace above, unless you left that out of your question. but in an example you would have

```
namespace My.NameSpace.Here {
   public static ListEditSelectionMode SelectionMode { get; set; }
}
```